# INSTALL PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED

Tags: android, manifest

Trying to build an Android app for a class. I keep getting the error in the title. This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Grille.play.webapp_1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
            android:name="Grille.play.webapp_1.War"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Grille.play.webapp_1.Jabbawocky"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jabbawocky"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Grille.play.webapp_1.NASA"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nas"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Grille.play.webapp_1.Roundball"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_roundball"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have no idea where the issue is. I'm about to start over if I can't figure this out, but I would like to understand so I don't screw up in the future.

Comment: you want to have all your activities with:  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> ?.. If so you need to add  android:taskAffinity="com.package.task_for_work_order_activity" to you activity tag

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your package name to be all lower case:

```
grille.play.webapp_1
```

Comment: It's indeed that problem. Package doesn't like it to be uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a service in a different process, don't forget to add **:** or **.** before the process name.

```
        <service
            android:name=".services.LocationUpdateService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:isolatedProcess="true"
            android:process=":location_update"/>
                             ^
```